# DataGridView is not updating with database,only works inside the function with parameter(object,EventArgs)

Tags: c#, linq

i have a DataTable with some data and i bind it with my DataGridView with this code .. database is updating but not the gridview :

```
private void showdetails()
{
    dataGridViewInventory.DataSource = null;
    dataGridViewInventory.Columns.Clear();
    var st= (from a in db.productInvertoryTables
             select a).ToList();
    dataGridViewInventory.DataSource = st;
    dataGridViewInventory.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
    dataGridViewInventory.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None;

    var st1 = from k1 in db.cartTables
              select k1;
    dataGridView2cart.DataSource = st1;
    dataGridView2cart.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
    dataGridView2cart.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None;
    dataGridView2cart.Refresh();
}
```

adding to the cart-

```
public void  AddToCart(int id,int count)
{            
    productInvertoryTable t = db.productInvertoryTables.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    cartTable ct = new cartTable();

    if (db.cartTables.SingleOrDefault(q => q.prod_Id == t.Id) == null)
    {
        ct.datee = DateTime.Today.ToString();
        ct.prod_Id = t.Id;
        ct.name = t.name;
        ct.quantity = count;
        ct.pricee = t.sellprice * count;
        db.cartTables.InsertOnSubmit(ct);
        t.quantity -= count;
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
    else
    {
        cartTable cct = db.cartTables.SingleOrDefault(q => q.prod_Id == t.Id);
        cct.quantity += count;
        t.quantity -= count;
        cct.pricee += (count * t.sellprice);
        cct.datee = DateTime.Today.ToString();
        db.SubmitChanges();
        showdetails();
    }         
}
```

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsLjO.png)

[after- hp laptop item should be decreasing by 1 after adding to cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6cx3.png)

Comment: what **productInvertoryTables** returns?

Comment: can you provide your `productInvertoryTables` code, so that I conclude your results?

Comment: can you show the class/code that does the update in your `DataTable`?. Also, please elaborate more what the problem is.

Comment: How the grid on the left is filling up? are you removing any row from the left grid when you add in cart?

Comment: @GeraldGonzales i added the codes

Answer (score 1):

Here is the updated code:

**Add to Cart:**

```
public void  AddToCart(int id,int count)
{            
    productInvertoryTable t = db.productInvertoryTables.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    cartTable ct = new cartTable();

    if (db.cartTables.SingleOrDefault(q => q.prod_Id == t.Id) == null)
    {
        ct.datee = DateTime.Today.ToString();
        ct.prod_Id = t.Id;
        ct.name = t.name;
        ct.quantity = count;
        ct.pricee = t.sellprice * count;
        db.cartTables.InsertOnSubmit(ct);
        t.quantity -= count;
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
    else
    {
        cartTable cct = db.cartTables.SingleOrDefault(q => q.prod_Id == t.Id);
        cct.quantity += count;
        t.quantity -= count;
        cct.pricee += (count * t.sellprice);
        cct.datee = DateTime.Today.ToString();
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }

    showdetails(id); //Move outside to refresh the main and cart grid after save/update
}
```

**Update Grid:**

```
private void showdetails(int id)
{
   //dataGridViewInventory.DataSource = null; 
   //dataGridViewInventory.Columns.Clear();
    var st= from a in db.productInvertoryTables
             select a
    dataGridViewInventory.DataSource = st.ToList(); //Updated
    dataGridViewInventory.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
    dataGridViewInventory.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None;

    var st1 = from k1 in db.cartTables
              where k1.prod_Id == id
              select k1;
    dataGridView2cart.DataSource = st1.ToList(); //Updated
    dataGridView2cart.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
    dataGridView2cart.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None;
}
```

Let me know if it works, best regards.

Comment: To debug your code put breakpoint on var st and check if its returning any values on your database. And it its not, make sure productInvertoryTables really have a value also check your db entities connection string is correct. You can take the screen shot and add it on your post.

Comment: Please post your code of your add to cart so we can see your code which I think the missing link is located. I assume that you updated the productInvertoryTables first then refresh it again to load the updated data.

Comment: gridview of productInvertoryTables still not updating :( though database is updating as before

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using [Binding List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx) instead of `List`? It supports databinding and fires off events when the collection is modified.

```
var bindingList = new BindingList<ProductInvertoryTable>(st);
```

Then assign this variable to the datasource.

```
var st= from a in db.productInvertoryTables
        select a;
var bindinglist = new BindingList<ProductInvertoryTable>(st.ToList()); 
dataGridViewInventory.DataSource = bindinglist;
dataGridViewInventory.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
dataGridViewInventory.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None;
```

Comment: bro it shows error ! :(
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<demoProject.productInvertoryTable>' to 'System.ComponentModel.BindingList<demoProject.productInvertoryTable>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: I updated my answer. I think you need to convert the `st` to a `List` first before converting to `BindingList`.

Comment: applied your solution bt it doesnt work :( 
it only works inside the function with parameter(object,EventArgs)
private void AddToCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)